# tf profiler gives same FLOPs regardless of input shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to measure floating point operations in a model, and how much they increase as you change the input shape. I'm using the following code snippet:

```
import tensorflow
import keras
import tensorflow    as tf
import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np
import keras.backend         as K
import tensorflow            as tf
from keras.layers            import Input
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50      import ResNet50

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing         import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input
import numpy as np

def pre_process(img_size = (224, 224) ):
    x = np.random.rand(img_size[0],img_size[1],img_size[2])
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    x = preprocess_input(x)

    return x

def get_total_flops(graph,session,model):
        
    run_meta = tf.compat.v1.RunMetadata()
    opts = tf.compat.v1.profiler.ProfileOptionBuilder.float_operation()

    flops = tf.compat.v1.profiler.profile(graph=graph,
        run_meta=run_meta, cmd="scope", options=opts
    )

    return flops.total_float_ops


session = tf.compat.v1.Session()
graph = tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()
            
INPUT_SHAPE = (128,128,3)
    
model = ResNet50(weights= None,input_tensor=Input(shape=INPUT_SHAPE),classes=1)
with graph.as_default():
    with session.as_default():
        x     = pre_process(img_size=INPUT_SHAPE)
        
        for i in range(20):
            preds = model.predict(x)

        total_flops = get_total_flops(graph,session,model)
        
        print('total_flops: ', total_flops)
```

the output is:

```
total_flops: 23563360
```

I'm getting the exactly same number for different INPUT_SHAPES. eg `INPUT_SHAPE=(256,256,3)`,`INPUT_SHAPE=(512,512,3)`

As i understood, a bigger image will lead to more operations in convolution layers, so, why it is returning the exactly same FLOPs ?

Answer (score 1):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework.convert_to_constants import convert_variables_to_constants_v2_as_graph

def get_flops(model):
    concrete = tf.function(lambda inputs: model(inputs))
    concrete_func = concrete.get_concrete_function(
        [tf.TensorSpec([1, *inputs.shape[1:]]) for inputs in model.inputs])
    frozen_func, graph_def = convert_variables_to_constants_v2_as_graph(concrete_func)
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
        tf.graph_util.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
        run_meta = tf.compat.v1.RunMetadata()
        opts = tf.compat.v1.profiler.ProfileOptionBuilder.float_operation()
        flops = tf.compat.v1.profiler.profile(graph=graph, run_meta=run_meta, cmd="op", options=opts)
        return flops.total_float_ops
```

I tested this problem with the above code and it worked for me. Maybe this helps you.